# Crawl / Scrape the DOM of a single webpage then re-render it?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, web-crawler, data-extraction, domcrawler

**I would like to crawl / scrape the Dom of a given URL and re-render it on another URL. This is for Growth Hacking tool purpose**

An example would be, I want to rerender the page http://x.com/x.html.

1. I browse http://example.com/render?url=http://x.com/x.html
2. I suck the DOM content of http://x.com/x.html on the server side
3. I re-render the sucked DOM content keeping all the dependencies intact.

The objective of this would be to manipulate the DOM like would be done by a ChromeExtension but without any extension required. This could work on any browser.

As I keep all the original dependencies (URL of the assets: images / js / CSS...) I can re-render the same page with the same design and my additional DOM modifications.

**I've made few experimentations and this work fine. But my question is, is this scalable ?
What about on the legal side ? Can I be brought to justice by the original website owner (even if there isn't any scam or fraud intention) ?
Would you have any recommendation ?**

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This is about programming ! I'm looking for the best code pattern to make this scalable and working well.

Comment: The wording which I used could use some work. I have changed it for what I will use in the future. However, the question is off-topic as written. Please see the two links I provided in my original comment.

Comment: To be a bit more specific: scalable is a yes/no question which is primarily opinion based, or based on information not provided. Legal questions are off-topic. Perhaps on [law.se] would be appropriate (maybe other sites). Recommendations: is an open-ended request which is [something to be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You *might* be able to get the recommendation request down to something on-topic, but I'm not seeing it. Overall, this is mostly a question which is asking for a discussion, and not "a practical, answerable problem". Thus, the question is off-topic.